# Red5 / Adobe Streaming server live streaming

Tags: flash, video, streaming

Is it possible to capture/encode a video file on a slow machine, then upload it live to a Red5 or Adobe Streaming server, and have that server stream to file live to flash clients?

If so, what protocol is used to stream the data from the encoding machine to the Red5 / Adobe server?

I see a lot of things about RTMP, but am I correct that this protocol is used between Streaming Server and Flash client, but not from encoding machine to Streaming Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to stream from your computer to Red5 or FMS using Flash Player and the broadcaster in this case does use RTMP to connect and transfer A/V data to the server. There are simple broadcast and recorder applications in the Red5 source tree to get you started.

The Red5 project may be found here: http://code.google.com/p/red5

The source for the "simple" broadcaster is here (simpleBroadcaster.fla): http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/